# Colour text in facet by legend color in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-text

I have a sample dataframe:

dput(data)

```
structure(list(DAF = c(0.00704225, 0.00352113, 0.00352113, 0.028169, 
0.00352113, 0.00704225, 0.0105634, 0.00352113, 0.0105634, 0.00352113, 
0.00352113, 0.00352113, 0.0176056, 0.0140845, 0.00352113, 0.0140845, 
0.00352113, 0.0105634, 0.00352113, 0.00352113, 0.0140845, 0.00352113, 
0.084507, 0.00352113, 0.0669014, 0.00704225, 0.00352113, 0.00352113, 
0.00704225, 0.00352113, 0.00704225, 0.00352113, 0.00352113, 0.028169, 
0.00352113, 0.00704225, 0.0105634, 0.00352113, 0.0105634, 0.00352113, 
0.00352113, 0.00352113, 0.0176056, 0.0140845, 0.00352113, 0.0140845, 
0.00352113, 0.0105634, 0.00352113, 0.00352113, 0.0140845, 0.00352113, 
0.084507, 0.00352113, 0.0669014, 0.00704225, 0.00352113, 0.00352113, 
0.00704225, 0.00352113), TYPE = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("All SVs", "bDEL"), class = "factor"), 
Function = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Genic", "Intergenic"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DAF", "TYPE", "Function"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -60L))
```

I have plotted using"

```
p1<-ggplot(sv,aes(x=DAF,y=..density..,fill=Function))+geom_histogram(position="dodge",binwidth=0.02)+facet_wrap( ~ TYPE, scales = "free",ncol=2)
```

The annotated text from the dataframe:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(x = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), y = c(20L, 
17L, 14L, 35L, 30L, 25L), labs = structure(c(3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 5L), .Label = c("mean=0.0173", "mean=0.0190", "mean=0.0415", 
"mean=0.0440", "p=0.0393", "p=1.47e-08"), class = "factor"), 
    TYPE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("All SVs", 
    "bDEL"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", "y", "labs", 
"TYPE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


p2<-p1+geom_text(aes(x, y, label=labs),size=1,data=dat,inherit.aes = F)
```

which gives the following plot:

[image]

However, i would need to color the text "mean=..." inside each facet by the corresponding colour of the legends.  i.e in facet All SVs, 'mean=0.0415' should be in "Genic" color and "mean=0.0440' in 'Intergenic' color.

Comment: How do you know which mean gets which function colour if it is not in `dat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a column to "dat" to represent what group each row/label should be in.  I used `NA` for the p-values.

```
dat$Function = c("Genic", "Intergenic", NA, "Genic", "Intergenic", NA)
```

Then you can map this variable to `color` in `geom_text`.  You can avoid adding the `NA` to the legend by using `show.legend = FALSE`.

```
p1 + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = labs, color = Function), 
               size = 1, data = dat, inherit.aes = FALSE, show.legend = FALSE)
```

The `NA` color defaults to `grey50`, which you could change to something else if needed in `scale_color_discrete`.

```
p1 + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = labs, color = Function), 
               size = 1, data = dat, inherit.aes = FALSE, show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_color_discrete(na.value = "black")
```

Comment: it works!! 1.how can i change the strip width holding the titles "All SVs' and "bDEL". I tried `strip.background = element_rect(size = 0.5)` which does not have any effect!!   2. COuld it be possible to add titles to each facet like a,b,c,d... which is normal done using ggtitle()

Comment: @chas I think the width of the strip will always be as wide as the plot, although you can change the justification of the titles and/or remove the strip background all together via some of the `theme` arguments.  You can add/change titles via `labeller` in `facet_wrap` or by changing the levels of the factor used as the facet variable.